# How to have optional values in RequestMapping

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have an address as following www.example.com/myaction, I need to make my current method to accept one optional value as following:

```
www.example.com/myaction/1010
www.example.com/myaction/3493
```

I made the method as following to accept the optional value but it does not work.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/myaction", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String myForm(@RequestParam(required=false) String id,@ModelAttribute ....)
{
  ...
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to send the params through the url?

Comment: @LukeSpringWalker form will be posted but I have these ids in address as well.

Comment: You just need to make optional one of the form's values? nothing to do with the ids in the address?

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to register two mappings,

```
@RequestMapping(value="/myaction/{id}", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String myForm(@PathVariable String id,@ModelAttribute ....) {... }
```

and

```
@RequestMapping(value="/myaction", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String myForm2(@ModelAttribute ....) {... }
```

an alternative is to write a custom path matcher such as in [this blog post](http://java.dzone.com/articles/spring-3-webmvc-optional-path), but IMO, no need for this as you don't have too many variations.
Note also @Braj's comment, you can use regex to make your mapping accepting digits only `/myaction/{id:\d+}`

Comment: Make the url more closer like `@RequestMapping(value="/myaction/{id:\d+}", method=RequestMethod.POST)` using regex that accepts id having 1 or more digits only. This will not match with this `www.example.com/myaction/myid` url

Comment: true, and good practice, but I leave this up to the OP, my point was just about the optional variable...but added it to the answer so that is more obvious, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Did u try this option., where id is the value that will be coming as parameter value.

> @RequestMapping(value="/myaction/{id}", method=RequestMethod.POST)
>
> public String myForm(@PathVariable String id,@ModelAttribute ....) 
>   {... }

Here is an example too., [link](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-requestmapping)

Comment: in that case {id} would not be optional.